# A query with a subquery in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

Need help implementing this query on Django ORM:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROUND(AVG(foo) OVER w) AS avg_foo
  FROM t1
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY DATE_PART('doy', date))
) AS t2
```

I tried to write something like this:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    avg_foo=Round(
        Window(
            expression=Avg('foo'),
            partition_by=Extract('date', 'doy')
        )
    )
)
```

But if I start filtering the query by date, the average value is calculated from the truncated selection, unlike RawQuery.

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    foo = models.IntegerField()
```